# Component to preview a xml source in primefaces

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces

I want to know if there is one component to show a xml source in browser?

Or other way to display

Thanks

Comment: What specifically do you need? What exactly have you tried and how exactly were the results insufficient? This is already possible with just `<h:outputText>`.

Comment: @BalusC I want to show my xml formated as XML code like we can see in internet explorer. It´s possible?